# ATAPI library not working in windows 7 ×64

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, 64-bit, tapi

I'm trying to make a caller id detector using ATAPI, or Itapi 3 (Gulmar) but in my os it's not working the following exception appears:

> System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'ITapi3, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36377d9f6f1f4883' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>     Source=IncomingSample
>     FileName=ITapi3, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36377d9f6f1f4883
>     FusionLog
>     ==== Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: User = Dragon-PC\Dragon
>   LOG: DisplayName = ITapi3, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36377d9f6f1f4883
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Dragon/Downloads/Compressed/ITapi3_Binaries/bin/Samples/Samples/IncomingSample/bin/x64/Release/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : IncomingSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>     ===
>   LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Dragon\Downloads\Compressed\ITapi3_Binaries\bin\Samples\Samples\IncomingSample\bin\x64\Release\IncomingSample.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: ITapi3, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36377d9f6f1f4883
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Dragon/Downloads/Compressed/ITapi3_Binaries/bin/Samples/Samples/IncomingSample/bin/x64/Release/ITapi3.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
>
> StackTrace:
>          at IncomingSample.IncomingForm..ctor()
>          at IncomingSample.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Dragon\Downloads\Compressed\ITapi3_Binaries\bin\Samples\Samples\IncomingSample\Program.cs:line 17
>     InnerException:

I tried to set the Active solution platform for  x64 and x86 but it didn't work, what can i do?

Comment: I am assuming that this file exists ?
file:///C:/Users/Dragon/Downloads/Compressed/ITapi3_Binaries/bin/Samples/Samples/IncomingSample/bin/x64/Release/ITapi3.DLL

Answer (score 5):

Atapi library will work on Windows 7 64 bit (I'm using it for a long time) but you have to compile your project for platform target x86 (if you are compiling atapi library also set to x86)

Best regards,
Piotr